# Conditional sum total formula for SharePoint list column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, calculated-columns, sharepoint-list

I have created a SharePoint list with a calculated column.

How to get sum totals of one column based for specific rows that meet a certain condition?

Row 1:

- Column Name: Company A
- Column Payments: 150
- Column Totals: 150

Row 2:

- Column Name: Company A
- Column Payments: 50
- Column Totals: 200

The "Column Totals" must add total for every record grouped for each Company Name.

`=IF([Company]="Company A",SUM([Payment]),[Column Totals])`

Answer (score 0):

Each value in the SharePoint list column is at the same level, and the corresponding record can be calculated, but it cannot be added like an excel file, where you can add total for every record grouped for each Company Name. You can try using [Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/powerapps-overview) to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible using SharePoint calculated columns and formulas.

You cannot get column values from another rows/list items (from same or different SharePoint list) in formula, this is a known limitation of formulas in SharePoint:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Introduction to SharePoint formulas and functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-sharepoint-formulas-and-functions-94e1b4cc-cd1c-49c2-80ec-90c9b9591f47#bm3)

**Reference**: [How to validate the choice column in SharePoint 2016 custom list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/307693/how-to-validate-the-choice-column-in-sharepoint-2016-custom-list/307697#307697)